# YAML-JSON converter; something flawed?

Tags: python, ruby, json, perl, yaml

I'm trying to get a simple YAML to JSON converter going in Python, but it doesn't seem correct at all. I am a native Perl/Ruby programmer so I have three scripts, and one input file:

**testinput.yaml**

```
---
default:
  default:
    line_one: '[I]<description>[/I]'
    line_three: '<creator>'
    line_two: '<title> [<type>]'
    link_to: '<citation>'
```

and one Python/Perl/Ruby script each that do in my mind the exact same thing:

**y2j.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'yaml'
yml = YAML.load_file('testinput.yaml')
json = JSON.dump(yml)

puts json
```

**y2j.pl**

```
use JSON;
use YAML;
my $filename = "testinput.yaml";
my $yaml  = YAML::LoadFile($filename);
print encode_json($yaml);
```

**y2j.py**

```
import yaml
import json


stream = open("testinput.yaml", 'r')
data = yaml.load_all(stream)
json = json.dumps(data)

print(json)
enter code here
```

then the output:

**ruby y2j.rb**

```
{"default":{"default":{"link_to":"<citation>","line_two":"<title> [<type>]","line_three":"<creator>","line_one":"[I]<description>[/I]"}}}
```

**perl y2j.pl**

```
{"default":{"default":{"line_three":"<creator>","line_two":"<title> [<type>]","link_to":"<citation>","line_one":"[I]<description>[/I]"}}}
```

*(so far, so good)*

**python y2j.py**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y2j.py", line 7, in <module>
    json = json.dumps(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 367, in encode
    chunks = list(self.iterencode(o))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 317, in _iterencode
    for chunk in self._iterencode_default(o, markers):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 323, in _    iterencode_default
    newobj = self.default(o)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/encoder.py", line 344, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <generator object load_all at 0x15a81e0> is not JSON serializable
```

Is there something completely obvious that I am missing here?

Comment: UGH, thanks, changed, works as expected.

Comment: Do not use `json` for variable name, it shadows (override) the `json` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yaml.load_all`, per the error message, is a [*generator*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators). See the following example from [the documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation):

```
>>> for data in yaml.load_all(documents):
...     print data

{'description': 'A set of handgear with sparks that crackle across its knuckleguards.\n',
'name': "The Set of Gauntlets 'Pauraegen'"}
{'description': 'A set of gauntlets that gives off a foul, acrid odour yet remains untarnished.\n',
'name': "The Set of Gauntlets 'Paurnen'"}
{'description': 'A set of handgear, freezing with unnatural cold.\n',
'name': "The Set of Gauntlets 'Paurnimmen'"}
```

Note that this code *iterates over* the generator to access its contents.

Instead, you should `load` the data (or, to reduce security risks, `safe_load`). I think your Python version should therefore look like:

```
import json

import yaml

with open("testinput.yaml") as stream:
    yaml_data = yaml.safe_load(stream)
json_data = json.dumps(yaml_data)

print(json_data)
```

Note the following:

- `import` laid out per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/);
- Use of `with` context manager to handle the file; and
- Use of the name `json_data` to avoid shadowing the `json` library.

If you *will* have multiple documents in the file, you could try e.g. `yaml_data = list(yaml.load_all(stream))`.